# Why does SparkJava not process the second request on the same connection?

Tags: java, spark-java, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have written a small server with a REST-API using SparkJava. I try to query the REST-API with an Apache Httpclient. With this client, I open a connection and send a first request to the server and receive a response. Then I reuse the same connection to send a second request to the server. The request is transmitted but the server does not process it. Does anyone know, what I am doing wrong?

Here a minimal working example:

Maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Server class:

```
package minimal;

import spark.Spark;

public class Server {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Spark.post("/a", (req, resp) -> {
          resp.status(204);
          return "";
        });
    Spark.post("/b", (req, resp) -> {
          resp.status(204);
          return "";
        });
    Spark.before((req, res) -> {
          System.out.println("Before: Request from " + req.ip() + " received " + req.pathInfo());
        });
    Spark.after((req, res) -> {
          System.out.println("After: Request from " + req.ip() + " received " + req.pathInfo());
        });
  }
}
```

Client class:

```
package minimal;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
      HttpPost httpPost1 = new HttpPost("http://localhost:4567/a");
      try (CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpPost1)) {
        System.out.println(response1.getCode() + " " + response1.getReasonPhrase());
      }

      HttpPost httpPost2 = new HttpPost("http://localhost:4567/b");
      try (CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost2)) {
        System.out.println(response2.getCode() + " " + response2.getReasonPhrase());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The server output on the console:

```
Before: Request from 127.0.0.1 received /a
After: Request from 127.0.0.1 received /a
```

Here the shortened output of a tcpdump:

```
14:52:15.210468 IP localhost.44020 > localhost.4567:
POST /a HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:4567
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.0.3 (Java/1.8.0_282)

14:52:15.271563 IP localhost.4567 > localhost.44020:
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Tue, 27 Apr 2021 12:52:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Server: Jetty(9.4.26.v20200117)

14:52:15.277376 IP localhost.44020 > localhost.4567:
POST /b HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:4567
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.0.3 (Java/1.8.0_282)
```

Thereafter no response of the Server was recorded anymore.

Comment: here check this article on how to manage the http connections https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the missing processing of the SparkJava server was the following additional maven dependency I had in the project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.7.1.1.0-565</version>
        </dependency>
```

After removing this dependency, the SparkJava server works as expected.

Comment: This particular Spark framework is something totally different from the SparkJava you are using

Comment: I am aware of it. I am trying to implement a REST-Sink for an Apache Spark Streaming job. To test the REST API client I use the SparkJava framework. Due to the dependency problems I moved the test server to a different submodule.

Comment: in this case, be aware that all of these rest calls in spark streaming have to be made in an asynchronous manner otherwise you have a very high chance to get a stall with your singlethreaded way, the spark streaming is by nature a hi-load and a hi-throughput process/system so just be aware, either combine these several calls into logical blocks or into one method and call it in different threads or else.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. My idea was to execute the REST calls for authentication and setting up the data submission session when the Spark Sink is initialized, the submission of data would be made asynchronously and the closing of the session and the logoff would be made when closing the Spark Sink.

Comment: again, depending on your auth mechanism you have to be aware about the auth tokens expiration if it's oauth/oauth2 mechanism or the likes and in this particular case you have to handle the expiration of the auth tokens externally, via separate service thread/job with some data buffering, because if auth token expires while you're pushing the data to your WS the import will break and the streaming data will be stuck or lost

Answer (score 0):

Here's the client sample please try it out and see if it works for you.
I tested it and it worked fine.

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.IOException;

public class T1 {

   static void runPost(CloseableHttpClient c,String s)
    {
            HttpPost httpPost1 = new HttpPost(s);
            try(CloseableHttpResponse response1 = c.execute(httpPost1)) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " +
                         response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " " +
                         response1.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try(CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            T1.runPost(httpclient, "http://localhost:4567/a");
            T1.runPost(httpclient, "http://localhost:4567/b");
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use google instead of the SparkJava server also my minimal example client is working. I tried out your code. When I allow two different connections for the two requests to the SparkJava server, then it works. But if I set ```cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(1);``` , then I have the same behavior as in my minimal working example: Only one request is processed by the SparkJava server. If I leave maximal 2 parallel connections to the same host but start three requests, then only two requests are processed by SparkJava server.

Comment: so where is the problem? I used your server with SparkJava too it's working perfectly it really depends on the client how you want to use / reuse the connections or connection pools. You tweak the ConnectionManager as much as you like. I used the 2 because your example used only 2 GET requests you can put as many as you like and tweak the mentioned ConnectionManager.

Comment: Since I am using a single threaded client that has to send requests in a specified sequence, I would reuse a single TCP connection for all HTTP requests. But whenever I send the second HTTP request on the same TCP connection, the request is sent (based on tcpdump) but the server does not process the second request.

Comment: I've tested your server and the client. I've changed the client to the mentioned code above and I don't get any errors. To chain the requests you can use `CompletableFutures.andThen()` methods etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have tried your implementation but unfortunately, the second request to /b is sent but the server does not process it. The server also does not throw an Exception it is just doing nothing. If it works for you, may it be related to the Java version? I am using openjdk version "1.8.0_292".

Comment: Here's the info - INFO Server:360 - jetty-9.4.31.v20200723; built: 2020-07-23T17:57:36.812Z; git: 450ba27947e13e66baa8cd1ce7e85a4461cacc1d; jvm 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04